# cURL Command in linux to return http response code

Tags: linux, bash, http, curl

Please i want to use the cURL command in linux OS to return as a result just the http response code which is "200" if it is okey

am using that command:

```
curl -I -L domain.com
```

but this is returning for me a full text like this

```
HTTP/1.1 **200** OK
Date: Thu, 27 Feb 2014 19:32:45 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.25 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 PHP/5.4.19
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.19
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=bb8aabf4a5419dbd20d56b285199f865; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Type: text/html
```

so please i just need the response code and not the whole text

Regards

Answer (score 10):

```
curl -s -o out.html -w '%{http_code}' http://www.example.com
```

Comment: this is returing the whole source of the index

Comment: ohhh yes . thanks alot
i saw the out.html .. not the result on the terminal. thanks sir

Comment: @user3178889: If you are satisfied with Sabuj's answer. Please click the check mark in front of his answer to accept it. This way it is clear that your question was successfully answered.

Comment: I wanted to pull a website html source as a text file, changed out.html to out.txt and the above command worked. Thanks!

Comment: This is prohibitively slow if the body is large.

Answer (score 1):

Running the following will supress the output so you won't have any cleanup.

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}' 127.0.0.1:80
```

Example above uses localhost and port 80

Comment: Yes, it provides the http code (i.e. 200, etc.)

root@70349a8eaf2c:/# curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}' 127.0.0.1:80
**200**root@70349a8eaf2c:/#                                                                                                                                                                    root@70349a8eaf2c:/#